# Ubuntu 19.10 gnome-shell crashes after changing keyboard

Tags: gnome, keyboard, gnome-shell, mutter

Updated to Ubuntu 19.10 Eoan, changing keyboard (from zh-cn to es-es) crashes gnome-shell, and displays that logoff is needed, but clicking logoff button is useless (won't work). Reboot, log in, and a black screen with movable cursur will be displayed. After some time, the crash screen will again be displayed.

Checked `journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell`, a lot of `gnome-shell[1907]: _clutter_stage_queue_event: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_STAGE (stage)' failed` was found.

Use tty3 to login and deleting `~/.config/dconf/user` would help logging in to desktop environment (gnome won't display dock, and have no settings of dock for some reason though), but changing keyboard still crashes gnome as before.

I tried adding disco and focal apt source into sources.list, and use aptitude to upgrade, or downgrade gnome to other versions. Things won't work either (can't even login).

After some googling, I found a possibly related PR: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/merge_requests/764, but this commit is on 3.35.1, not 3.34.

Is there any ways to use that patch without compiling it myself, or if there are any workarounds that can solve the problem (e.g. rollback)? Thanks for your help!